# Simple conditional formatting in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a sample data frame as follows:

```
structure(list(CellType = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("CellA", "CellB", "CellC"), class = "factor"), Gene1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5), Gene2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5), Gene3 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Is there a simple way to apply conditional formatting to numerical values to the entire data frame such that all values below 0.3 appear in red  and rest in standard black colour?

Thanks!

Comment: Appear in red where? When you print to the console?

Comment: Yes exactly, just the numerical values need to appear red (not the cell background)